# Optionset change event is not being triggered via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the html:

```
<select id="langOptionSet">
      <option value="english">English</option>
      <option value="spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>
```

Here is the script which i have written for language change:

```
$(function(){
SetSelectedLanguageText();
}); 

var SetSelectedLanguageText = (function ($){
    var language = $("#langOptionSet option:selected").val();
alert(language);
$.ajax({
    url: 'languages.xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('translation').each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var text = $(this).find(language).text();
            $("." + id).html(text);
        });
    }
}); 


$("#langOptionSet").change(function() {
SetSelectedLanguageText();
});
```

But the function `SetSelectedLanguageText` is not being triggered even on page load. What's wrong with this script?

thanks

Comment: If this is the exact code you have, then you have a syntax error: *`SyntaxError: missing } after function body`*. You are never closing the function you started defining with `(function ($){`. The other problem is that you never pass a value to `SetSelectedLanguageText`, so `$` will be undefined and you will get the error *`TypeError: $ is not a function`*. If you want `$` to refer to jQuery, just remove it from the function definition. If you fix these two things, it seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/3R4e2/ (as far as I can test it).

Comment: If haven't already, you should learn how to debug JavaScript: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners.

Comment: @FelixKling After your mentioned solution it is working on page load, but the function is not being triggered when i change optionset value. Any thoughts? thanks